# How to get values from a map with #js literal

Tags: clojurescript

I am new to clojure. I have a map fooBar :

```
#js {:foo 1, :bar 2}
```

I want to get foo. I have tried :

```
(:foo fooBar)
(get fooBar :foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be simple `field access`  :

```
(.-foo fooBar)
```

Comment: Also handy: (.. -foo -bar -baz fooBar) for nested access. Check out cljs-bean for a library around this.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at the `cljs-oops` lib.  See "JavaScript Interop" section of https://cljs.info